# In-game or "In game"

Tags: hyphenation

The sentence is "In-game currency can be converted into Ethereum, or used to upgrade the player".

Is it "In-game" or "In game"?

Comment: *In-game* is correct.

Comment: In general (there are, of course, many exceptions), when a phrase like "in game" is used as an adjective, a hyphen is added.  This helps differentiate between the meaning "currency that is used in the game" and " some attribute or activity inside the game currency".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in this sentence you would need a hyphen for in-game.

This is an example of a compound adjective.  [Here's the explanation from Grammar Book:](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp)

> Rule 1. Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a
>   noun they modify and act as a single idea.
>
> Examples: an off-campus apartment, state-of-the-art design

In-game modifies currency, and therefore you should use a hyphen.

Comment: Many people here do not provide answers to questions that show zero research or are otherwise substandard.

Comment: Yes, I just joined mid-September, so this was before I had any idea of that unwritten, self-enforced rule.  Oh boy! Look at all those hyphens!